# Updated field in rendering variant not working

Tags: sxa, presentation

The requirement was to show the last updated date and time of the item in the page. So I tried to create a rendering variant of page content  with field as `Updated`  (which is there for every item provided by the standard template).

However I am not able to see the date and time when selecting the rendering variant. While accessing the variant nothing is coming up as if such field does not exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So its taking index field

Comment: It's taking the actual name - which is "__Updated". The "Updated" you see is the readable version (the title)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the updated fields is actually `__Updated` and not just `Updated`. Did you try that as field name in the variant?

Answer (score 0):

@Gatogordo is correct that the field name is different than the one you were testing.

Here is an example of `__Updated` working:

#### Scriban variant

[image: Scriban]

#### Field variant

[image: Field]

#### Page output

[image: Output]